# Changes made to the Python code not reflected on server in Fedora in Virtual Box(Not duplicate)

Tags: python, virtual-machine, fedora

I have a VM in Oracle virtual box which has Fedora24. I have my python server running (Django). There is no web server like Apache.However, when I make changes to the code the files are getting saved, but the changes are not reflected on the server.

I have to do **kill -15 processid of python** 
OR
**Restart my VM many times to see the changes.**

Any idea why this is happening? Have tried clearing the browser caches also.

Comment: "I have my python server running" : what is your "python server" ???

Comment: Django 1.9 Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You failed to provide enough context - like what exactly is "your python server", but anyway, you mention a browser cache so I assume it's a web server process. The point is: Python modules are imported only once per process, and once imported changes to the source files are totally irrelevant. So if you have a long running process, it **is** expected that you restart the process every time you deploy a new version of your modules.

Comment: But whenever I make changes in normal desktop, i.e without using the VM, this is not happening. The changes are immediately reflected.

Comment: What server are you running on the VM ? I assume you have a front web server (Apache, nginx or such) and your django app deployed thru WSGI ?

Comment: For development purpose its just the django server. I haven't hosted on Apache. So there is no front web server.

Comment: Ok. Then **please** edit your question with all these informations, it would have saved me quite some time (and will save time to anyone wanting to answer).